# best way to know bottom-line height of a pdf

Tags: pdf, luatex

For some project, I need to make a PDF of one page, with no margin whatsoever. The left, right and top margin are easy to set to 0, but I also need the pdf to have the exact height of what's inside, so I need to cut at the bottom of the depth of the final vbox. I'm using LuaTeX for this, and it's best if the vertical cutting of the pdf is done in a separate script (as I need multiple pass to generate the PDF I want).

What I'm thinking about is to output the absolute height of the depth of final box in the aux file, something like `XXXcutAt:10cm`, and then parse the aux file and pass this value to `pdfcrop` in a script.

I'm not sure about the best way to know this value though... Is there some obvious TeX-only way to get it that I'm missing? If not, reading the LuaTeX manual it seems `pdf.v` is what I want, but I'm a bit puzzled on the way to use it... Is there any code using it I could use as an example?

Comment: Would the documentclass `standalone` be sufficient to achieve what you want?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [`{standalone}`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standalone)...

Comment: Doesn't work no, the document is basically a paragraph with several lines and it must have a precise width, my experiments with `standalone` class seem to show that's it's not possible...

Comment: what you need is `\pagetotal` you can cat the page within (TeX) by `\pdfpageheight=\pagetotal` befor end

Comment: If you set \maxdepth=0pt then tex will adjust the box to have depth 0 anyway (or you could end the page with `\null` so you knew it had depth 0)

Comment: you shouldn't need to crop the pdf afterwards you should be able to set the pdf box in one pass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

This is plain tex but you could do the same in latex.

```
\setbox0=\vbox{\hsize=7.8cm
some text to fill out several lines of a paragraph with a high
proportion of g and y and f so that the depth is non zero
some text to fill out several lines of a paragraph with a high
proportion of g and y and f so that the depth is non zero
some text to fill out several lines of a paragraph with a high
proportion of g and y and f so that the depth is non zero
some text to fill out several lines of a paragraph with a high
proportion of g and y and f so that the depth is non zero
some text to fill out several lines of a paragraph with a high
proportion of g and y and f so that the depth is non zero
some text to fill out several lines of a paragraph with a high
proportion of g and y and f so that the depth is non zero}


\hoffset-1in
\voffset-1in
%asuming luatex 0.80 or older
\pdfpagewidth\wd0
\pdfpageheight\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax
\shipout\box0

\bye
```